# Laravel environment setup with Gitlab Runner

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, gitlab-ci-runner

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04
PHP: 7.2
Laravel: 5.8

When I try to run composer install for my gitlab runner image on my server. It shows the following error:

```
1320 : Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
1321 : Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
1322 : Problem 1
1323 : - Installation request for kylekatarnls/update-helper 1.2.0 -> satisfiable by kylekatarnls/update-helper[1.2.0].
1324 : - kylekatarnls/update-helper 1.2.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1.0 || ^2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
1325 : Problem 2
1326 : - kylekatarnls/update-helper 1.2.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1.0 || ^2.0.0 -> no matching package found.
1327 : - nesbot/carbon 1.39.1 requires kylekatarnls/update-helper ^1.1 -> satisfiable by kylekatarnls/update-helper[1.2.0].
1328 : - Installation request for nesbot/carbon 1.39.1 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.39.1].
```

It is the error when the Envoy file running `composer install`. It solves the problem when I run `composer update`, but I want to keep all the packages with same versions across different server. I try to renew composer lock file. It still shows that same error. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is your gitlab image using the same php version as you are?

Comment: @Jerodev Yes, it is running on PHP 7.2

Comment: This seems like a problem with your composer package, can you show how you install that?